# How to have Visual studio solution specific 'Use vcpkg' setting

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022, vcpkg, vcxproj

I'm using vcpkg installed dependencies (globally installed, not specific to project) for one Visual Studio solution, and conan for another Visual studio solution. For the conan solution, I have to use 'Use Vcpkg = No' in all of the projects inside the solution. For vcpkg solution, I need 'Use Vcpkg = Yes'.

[image: Visual Studio Project Properties]

Quick way to do this is by changing the property in C:\vcpkg\scripts\buildsystems\msbuild\vcpkg.props file.

[image]

However this changes the property for all Visual Studio solutions. When I work on solutions that need vcpkg, I have to undo this change I made.
This makes it difficult to work on both the solutions at the same time. Is there a way I can make this setting solution specific?